# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app (using Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a react app to Heroku, but I keep getting the error "Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app".

I've looked back at the other two react-apps I've deployed to Heroku to see if I forgot to add anything and I can't find any discrepancies. I see that it says it can't locate the index.html file, but I see that it is there. I then see something about "failing at portfolio@.1.0 build".

```
-----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > portfolio@0.1.0 build 
/tmp/build_fcb9f920aefd93116879e7ef6c75d3cc
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Could not find a required file.
remote:          Name: index.html
remote:          Searched in: 
/tmp/build_fcb9f920aefd93116879e7ef6c75d3cc/public
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is 
likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.L4l4f/_logs/2019-09- 
03T15_47_28_491Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can 
troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can 
remote:              help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to arcane-earth-93557.
```

Here is my package.json file as well

```
{
"name": "portfolio",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"engines": {
"npm": "6.9.0",
"node": "10.16.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"react-icons": "^3.7.0",
"react-router": "^2.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "3.1.1",
"react-scroll": "^1.7.13"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
}
}
```

I just want to know why I can't deploy.

Comment: "I see that it says it can't locate the index.html file, but I see that it is there." How do you see that it is there? Is it tracked? Is it in a directory called `public/` in the root of your repository? Do the cases of the file and directly exactly match?

Comment: I meant I can see the index.html file in the public folder that create-react-app automatically makes for you. However, I just decided to make a new react-app and just copied the code from the old one over and it deployed just fine. I guessing it was something with the file structure.